# Flot graph and Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, graph, flot

I'm having an issue with flot graph and Google Chrome.

The problem is reproduceable as follows:

1. Open an flot graph
2. Lock your screen
3. Unlock your screen and you will have to refresh the page to repaint the graph

It works fine under Firefox and IE.

Does anybody know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

It's probably a Chrome hardware-accelerated canvas bug.  Try visiting chrome://flags and turn off hardware-accelerated canvas, then see if the problem persists.  If it goes away, then you know that it was due to some interaction between Chrome, your graphics driver, and your graphics card, and you should file a bug with the Chrome team.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply

My setting were

Disable accelerated 2D canvas
Enable

I assume hardware acceleration is now off, and it is not working
Clicking on enable and it is working.

The problem has to with the hardware acceleration, I can se that now.
But I have to turn it ON and not OFF to get it working

Thanks again